# Forcing the NSOpenPanel View Option

Tags: cocoa, nsopenpanel

Is it possible to force or maybe even restrict the view option of an openPanel? For example I want the openPanel to only display the Cover flow view or Icon view upon activation. If restriction is not possible - how can I set the default view?

Thanks.

-paul.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to accomplish the same, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such API available in NSSavePanel nor NSOpenPanel, you may want to consider filing an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

you can make all non-selectable files be transparent via the delegate `- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url`

there are more delegate methods in the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate`